# in jquery using AJAX how to retrieve JSON data from remote server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using the following code to retrieve the status of transaction from a remote server. if I type that url in browser it is showing xml file with status value, and in fiddler the result looks like {"transaction":{"trxStatus":"3000"}} 0 and getting status 200. But when I execute that code the status value is not shown up instead of send a alert msg with 'success' comment. Can anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am not sure that my remote server does support 'jsonp' or not. I have got the JSON or XML format from them.
Another point is, if I use that url with user and password details in browser it is showing xml file with all values and in fiddler all values are shown up with a null (I don't know why {"transaction":[{"amount":"x","counter":"x","receiver":"x",},null]}. But when I execute that code the same 'success' alert appears, not displaying the value.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```html
This is my code
<html>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js">
        
            $(function () {
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                            url: 'http://www.example.com:8780/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx',
                            dataType: "jsonp",            
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            method: 'get',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#txttrxStatus').val(data.trxStatus);
                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                alert(err.statusText);
                            }
                        });
                  });
        </script>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
            <tr>
                <td> trxStatus</td>
                <td><input id="txttrxStatus" type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that a zero "0" at the end of the result?

Comment: You need to fix the example: <script> with src ends with </script>.
script with inner JS start with <script>

Comment: No the '0' at the end of the tree if we consider the root is Transaction then one sibling are- {values} and another sibling is {0}

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(data)` in your success handler?

Comment: also `error: function(xhr, txtStatus, err) { console.log(xhr, txtStatus, err); }`

Comment: What does the console Network response says?

Comment: my browser responds nothing, you can check with the url: http://www.bkashcluster.com:9080/dreamwave/merchant/trxcheck/sendmsg

Comment: Is there anyone to help me? i am really struggling